# SyntaxError: Unexpected token (61:16) for return (<div>...</div>)

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

Have a simple return including a div. Seems babel-loader is getting upset, can't see why. I'm not to hot on such but just trying to rebuild an older project. npm run build:all eventually gets upset with my return that tries to push back a div.

If I take out the div and just do

Debug:

```
Hash: 3fa4f48a100a48c899c6
Version: webpack 4.41.1
Time: 228ms
Built at: 10/13/2019 1:37:03 PM
 1 asset
Entrypoint main = window_size.min.js
[1] ./src/lib/index.js 165 bytes {0} [built]
    + 1 hidden module

ERROR in ./src/lib/components/window_size.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (61:16)

  59 |             
  60 |             return (
> 61 |                 <div id={id}>
     |                 ^
  62 |                     Width: {width} Height: {height} &nbsp;
  63 |                 </div>
  64 |             );

 @ ./src/lib/index.js 2:0-79 4:0-34
```

Versions:

```
"babel-core": "^6.26.3",
"babel-eslint": "^8.2.3",
"babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
"copyfiles": "^2.0.0",
"babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
```

Comment: Is JSX syntax part of `babel-preset-react`?

Comment: Lol my hero, fixed.
 
npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-react